# How to enable github action to access secret property file

Tags: java, android, gradle, github, github-actions

I was working on an android project where alot of sensitive api keys were involved. These keys were stored in a specific gradle property file which is ignored by git.

```
secret.properties
apikey="938484738288274932228"
```

The question is how can I enable github actions to access this property file and the values inside it without pushing the file to git.

*already tried*
- making a fallback property file with blank values ( but the values might be required for future tests )

Comment: You could try using Transcrypt (not the Python one - [this library](https://github.com/elasticdog/transcrypt) by elasticdog) which allows you to "transparently encrypt files within a git repository", then store the password and/or cypher in your secrets as explained by Dinko below.

Comment: Interesting approach, I just need gradle to be able to access the values so this could work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So this is the method I used to make this work.

- First place base64 encode the file content of the property file you want to hide.
- Then add that base64 string into a Github secret by going to setting in Github web client
- Then set up GitHub action in the project and add the task to write decoded content into a file from GH secret

```
- name: Decode secrets.properties file
        env:
          SECRETS_PROPERTIES: ${{ secrets.SECRETS_PROPERTIES }}
        run: echo "$SECRETS_PROPERTIES" | base64 -d > ./secrets.properties
```

- In your build.gradle file ( the one either in the root or /app directory ) you need to place the following code in order to let Gradle load the properties from the `secrets.properties` file.

```
def secretsPropertiesFile = rootProject.file("./secrets.properties")
def secretsProperties = new Properties()
secretsProperties.load(new FileInputStream(secretsPropertiesFile))
```

- Accessing the values within gradle would be `secretsProperties['apikey']`

More resources:

- https://github.com/features/actions
- https://help.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows/creating-and-storing-encrypted-secrets

Comment: This is a nice approach though, but what if you want to clone the project to another machine from GitHub, and since you had those confidential files in gitignore so those wont be available.Is there any solution for this?

Comment: You need to talk to the maintainers to give you the hidden credentials outside of git. That's the only way. You should also make sure not to push them by mistake.